# NodeJS - Async Clear Interval Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having major issues stopping an async interval from continuing.

This starts the infinite interval:

```
task.interval = setIntervalAsync(
    async() => await this.sendTimer(task, savedGuild), interval);
```

Class that creates the bug:
https://pastebin.com/qq5tReFq

Line that doesn't do anything:

```js
while (task.interval)
  clearIntervalAsync(task.interval);
```

Sorry if this is unhelpful, but I have tried many different types and intervals and when `endTimers` is called the interval continues as if nothing has happened. Please send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const guildTimers = timers.currentTimers.get(req.params.id);
if (!guildTimers || guildTimers?.length <= 0)
    return res.json([]);

for (const timer of guildTimers)
    delete timer.interval; // <- the cause of the problem
```

I managed to find the issue. It was found in an external file, on the API, that allows the user to view the scheduled tasks.

`delete timer.interval` removed the reference to the interval, and therefore stopped it from being reset as `timer.interval` was undefined.